# Undefined indexes apeeared after submitting the form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I have a two step form. create.php and create2.php. Both pages are forms. After first form is filled user presses "Continue" and proceeds to the second form where i pass and store value from first form in hidden inputs. After filling and submitting second form, i want pop up window which means successful submission of the form and inserting all the data into database. It seems that everything is working fine and all data is in database, however i dont get pop up window, what i get is undefined index warning about my hidden inputs.

Ok here is code for create.php:

```
<form class="formcss" method="post" action="create2.php" id="reportform" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <fieldset style="background-color:white;">
    <legend style="font-size: 20px;">New Project</legend>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="small-8 large-8 columns">
        <label>Project Code: <small style="color:red;">*</small>

        <input type="text" name="code" maxlength="155" id="code" class="input input1 name" onkeyup="limitTextCount('code', 'divcount0', 155, 0);" onkeydown="limitTextCount('code', 'divcount0', 155, 0);" <?php if (isset($code)) echo 'value="'.$code.'"' ?>/>

        <label class="tool tool1" for="name" style="margin-top:-8px;">Code of the project</br>e.g. ASD001</label>
        </label>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="small-8 large-8 columns">
        <label>Project Name: <small style="color:red;">*</small>

        <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="155" id="title" class="input input1 name" onkeyup="limitTextCount('title', 'divcount0', 155, 0);" onkeydown="limitTextCount('title', 'divcount0', 155, 0);" <?php if (isset($title)) echo 'value="'.$title.'"' ?>/>

        <label class="tool tool1" for="name" style="margin-top:-8px;">Title of the project</br>e.g. Leon</label>
        </label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-8 large-8 columns">
        <label>Process              
            <div class="multiselect">               
                <div class="selectBox">                 
                    <select onclick="showCheckboxes()"  class="input input1 name">
                        <option>-- Select an option --</option>         
                    </select>
                    <div class="overSelect"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="scrollable" id="checkboxes">    
                <?php 
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $row[0] = cleanOutputData($row[0]);                             
                ?>      
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
                        <label style="height: 37px; width:80%; float:left;">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" style="margin-left:5%; width:15%;" name="process[]" id=<?php echo $row[0] ?>  value=<?php echo $row[0]?> /><?php echo $row[0] ?>
                        </label>
                        <label style="width:40%; margin-left:60%;"><input type="text" class="field" disabled style="width:40%;" name="numberpl[]" id=<?php echo $row[0] ?> />
                        </label>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php
                    }
                    mysql_free_result($result);
                ?>          
                </div>
            </div>
        </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="small-8 large-8 columns">
        <label>Comments
                <textarea style="resize:none;" class="input input1 name" name="remark" rows="8" cols="50" maxlength="255" id="remark" onkeyup="limitTextCount('remark', 'divcount5', 255, 0);" onkeydown="limitTextCount('remark', 'divcount5', 255, 0);"><?php if (isset($remark)) echo $remark ?></textarea>
            <label class="tool tool1" for="name"  style="left:-140px;">Further comments</label>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
        <label>&nbsp;<?php if (isset($remark)){ echo "<label id='divcount5'></label>"; echo "<script>limitTextCount('remark', 'divcount5', 255, 0);</script>";} else echo "<label id='divcount5'>255 characters remaining</label>";?></label>
    </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="row">
    <div class="small-8 large-8 columns">
        <input type = "submit" name ="submit" style="margin-left:600px; width:150px;" class="button" onclick="userSubmitted = true;" value = "Continue"/>

    </div>
    </div>

    <br/><br/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And for the second form create2.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //if user haven't sign in will redirect user to login page 
    if(empty($_SESSION['login_user'])){
        session_destroy();  
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
    $proc = isset($_POST['process'])?$_POST['process']:''; 
    //$proc=$_POST['process'];
    $len = count($proc); // getting length of ur array that u need to condition ur loop 

    $num = isset($_POST['numberpl'])?$_POST['numberpl']:''; 
    //$num=$_POST['numberpl'];
    //$len2 = count($num); // getting length of ur array that u need to condition ur loop   
    include 'verification/verify_form_details2.php';
    require_once('inc/config.php');
    //include 'verification/verify_form_details.php';
    ob_start();

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "pp";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
?>

<form class="formcss" method="POST" name="checkoutForm" action="create2.php#err" id="reportform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php
        $res = verifyFormFields();
    ?>
<!-- hidden inputs from first form(create.php) -->
    <input type="hidden" name="holdcode" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['code'])?$_POST['code']:'';?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="holdtitle" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['title'])?$_POST['title']:'';?>"> 

    <?php
        //an array of inputs
        for($y=0;$y<$len;$y++)
        {
    ?>
            <input type='hidden' name='holdprocess[]' value="<?php echo $proc[$y]?>">
            <input type='hidden' name='holdnumber[]' value="<?php echo $num[$y]?>">         
    <?php
        }
    ?>
<!-- hidden inputs from first form(create.php) -->
<br>

    <fieldset style="background-color:white;">
        <legend style="font-size: 20px;">Add Stuff</legend>
        <br><br><br>
        <div class="small-3 large-3 columns">
        <label>Choose username</label>
        <input placeholder="Search Me" id="box" type="text" />
        <div id="myAccordion">
        <?php for($i=321; $i<347; $i++)
            {
                echo "<h3>".chr($i)."</h3>";
                echo '<ul class="source">'; 
                $sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username LIKE '".chr($i+32)."%' ";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);       
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
                {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                    {  
                        $name= $row["username"];    
                        echo"<li>". $name ."</li>";
                    }
                } else 
                {
                    echo "0 results";
                }                       
                echo '</ul>';                   
            }
        ?>  
        </div>  
        </div>
        <div id="project" class="small-9 large-9 columns">
        <label style="font-size: 40px; margin-left:10%;">Project <?php echo isset($_POST['code'])?$_POST['code']:''; ?></label>
        <div class="rowone">
            <div id="leader">
            <label>Leader:</label>
                <div class="ui-widget-content">
                <div id="projLeader">
                    <ol>
                        <li class="placeholder" name="leader" <?php if (isset($leader)) echo 'value="'.$leader.'"' ?>>Add leader here</li>
                        <input type="hidden" name="leader" id="hiddenListInput1" />
                    </ol>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="checker">
            <label>Checker:</label>
                <div class="ui-widget-content">
                <div id="projChecker">
                <ol>
                    <li class="placeholder" name="checker" <?php if (isset($checker)) echo 'value="'.$checker.'"' ?>>Add checker here</li>
                    <input type="hidden" name="checker" id="hiddenListInput2" />
                </ol>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>                  
            <div id="info">
            <label>Information:</label>
                <div class="ui-widget-content">
                <ol>
                    <li>Total:</li>
                    <li>Total:</li>
                    <li>Total:</li>
                    <li>Total:</li>
                    <li>Total:</li>
                </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type = "submit" id="savebutton" style="margin-left:300px; width:150px;"  name ="submit" class="button" value = "Create Project" onclick="userSubmitted = true;" />   
        </div>
        </div>  
    <div id="formModal" class="reveal-modal small" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" data-options="close_on_background_click:false">
        <h2 id="modalTitle">Success!</h2>
        <div style="font-weight: 400;font-size: 1.5em; font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;">Your Accident Report was Successfully Submitted!</div>
        <div class="right">
            <a href="#" id="closebtn" onclick="popUpNo()" class="button">Ok</a>
        </div>
    </div>          
        <?php       
            if($counta==1) 
            {
                if($res=="")
                {   
                    $testing = JSON_encode($_SESSION['role']);
                    echo '<script>userSubmitted = true;</script>';
                    insertRecord();
                    echo "<script type ='text/javascript'>callShowAlert();</script>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "
                            <br><br><a style='color:red';> 
                                $res
                            </a>
                        ";
                }
            }
        ?>          
        <script>var testing = JSON.parse('<?= $testing; ?>');</script>          
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is what i got after submitting second form:

> **Notice**:
>
> Undefined index: process in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\1ver\create2.php
>   on line 9
>
> **Notice**:
>
> Undefined index: numberpl in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\1ver\create2.php
>   on line 12
>
> **Notice**:
>
> Undefined index: code in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\1ver\create2.php** on line **256**
>
> **Notice**:
>
> Undefined index: title in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\1ver\create2.php** on line **257**
>
> **Notice**:
>
> Undefined index: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\1ver\create2.php on
>   line 302

I'm using another php page to insert data into database. I just don't get what can be a problem. Thanks for any help

Comment: Is this code written in Create.php or create2.php? Please share code of both files.

Comment: Thanks for editing. But you didn't provide complete code for create2.php. However, I'd say you have to use a condition here before echoing something. I'm posting an answer, see if it helps.

Comment: @aj its a full code of create2.php thats al i got inside form

Answer (score 0):

Since POST array is not available for first time. Therefore, you are getting this error. If you really need to use those post variables, you should apply a condition in this case to avoid these errors.

I'm here adding for one, you can do the same for remaining.

Try this:

```
  <?php echo isset($_POST['code'])?$_POST['code']:''; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and edited my code, now im getting another notice: Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\1ver\create2.php on line 521 and 522 This is line 521 and 522:                             echo "Process: "."$proc[$y]"."      ";
echo "People required: "."$num[$y]"."     ";

Comment: Yes, its not appearing anymore

Comment: I did `isset` for each variable. still getting this error, you can view edited post.

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy There is a typo in your code. Please remove `"` after `.`

Comment: Not sure about in which line

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy In 521 and 522. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630577/undefined-indexes-apeeared-after-submitting-the-form/39632123?noredirect=1#comment66569570_39632123